# Filtering functionality not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In asp.net mvc, I am trying to filer a table but it's not working

In My Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    var employeesSearch = from s in db.Employees
                       select s;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
            employeesSearch = employeesSearch.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Site.SiteName.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Area.Area1.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Discipline.Discipline1.Contains(searchString));
   }

}
```

In my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Define "not working", that doesn't help us at all. What do you expect this code to do? Provide input and output values.

Comment: my apologies, It's just not filtering when button is clicked

Comment: You only read part of my comment and ignored the rest.

Comment: I want it to filter the table by whatever input you supply in the search bar

Comment: @Conor8630 have you tried my answer please!

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes I have, it worked!! Thank you once again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `ActionName` `ControllerName` and  `FormType` in your `@Html.BeginForm()` as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

And then in the `Index` method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    var employeesSearch = from s in db.Employees
                   select s;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        employeesSearch = employeesSearch.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString)
                               || s.Site.SiteName.Contains(searchString)
                               || s.Area.Area1.Contains(searchString)
                               || s.Discipline.Discipline1.Contains(searchString));
    }

   return View(employeesSearch.ToList());

}
```

It should work for you now.